# Pros and cons of using 20-25mm inner tube in a 32mm tire?

Tags: tire, innertube, hybrid-bike

I'm using 700x32mm Maxxis Detonator tires on my hybrid road bike. Although it is possible to find wider inner tubes that could fit better that tire, the 20-25mm ones are popular and available to buy more often.

I would like to know what are the pros and cons of using a 700 inner tube 20-25mm on this tire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much can a 700x23 inner tube stretch?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25370/how-much-can-a-700x23-inner-tube-stretch)

Comment: I've never had any difficulty at all buying inner tubes of the correct size. Your issue might be that the term "road bike" normally refers to a racing-style bike with drop handlebars, and these kinds of bikes typically come with 25mm tyres or similar. So, if you're searching for something like "road bike inner tube", that's what you'll find most often.

Comment: @DavidRicherby actually it's a good point, but I'm just searching for 700 inner tubes and looking for options available. Often sizes like 20-25mm or 23-25mm are available rather then bigger ones

Comment: @ojs this question is more related to get cons and pros of using a smaller inner tube, edited to make it clear.

Comment: The cons include the facts that you're apt to experience an unpleasant dip in the tire near the valve, and you're apt to need the tubes to be cheaper because they will fail more often.

Answer (score 5):

I use a 700x23 butyl inner tubes (I've tested Michelin, Pirelli and Kenda) in a 700x28 tyre and I've had no problems so far. But 700x20 one is 'too thin' in this set, so it can explode. It depends on the brand and you can't rely on the assumption that every inner tube will work in every tyre.